# Difference between Explicit and Fluent wait in Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

What is the main difference between Explicit wait and fluent wait in Selenium C#?
After reading many articles I could understand that we can set polling time in fluent wait. We can also tell fluent wait to ignore certain exception types.

But these two characteristics are also there in WebDriverWait (explicit wait). Default polling time can be changed by poling interval property. Also it doesn't throw any exception till timeout expires.

So I am in a confusion as to what is the main difference between the two waits?

Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`FluentWait` doesn't exist in C#, only in Java, [see the source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/search?q=FluentWait).

In C#, there is [`WebDriverWait`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/dotnet/src/webdriver/Support/WebDriverWait.cs) and [`DefaultWait`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/dotnet/src/webdriver/Support/DefaultWait%7BT%7D.cs). `WebDriverWait` inherits from `DefaultWait`.

```
public class WebDriverWait : DefaultWait<IWebDriver>
```

There's not really a lot of differences between the two other than their constructors. They both have the same options for setting `.IgnoreExceptionTypes`, `.Message`, `.PollingInterval`, and `.Timeout`. They both have the same defaults for `.PollingInterval` and `.Timeout`, 500ms.

A couple simple examples:

```
DefaultWait<IWebDriver> defaultWait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
defaultWait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // default is 500ms
defaultWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("login")));
```

vs

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("login")));
```

They both work the same way, I prefer `WebDriverWait` because it's syntax is shorter but that's a personal preference.

Comment: FluentWait does not exist it, but you can simulate fluent wait as described in the article.

Comment: @vitaliis Why call it `FluentWait` (referring to C#) if it doesn't exist in C#? Why not just refer to what actually exists in C#, `WebDriverWait` and `DefaultWait`?

Comment: Still, did you see any mention of FluentWait in the article? Thee only create fluentWait object that simulates the behaviour similar to FluentWait in Java.

Comment: @vitaliis Did you actually read the article that you posted? You're acting like it never referred to Fluent wait. Do a search for "FluentWait" (16 references) or "Fluent Wait" (18 references). That's 34 references... so Yes, I did see some mention of FluentWait in the article.

Comment: Of course I read it. There are fluentWait objects, not FluentWait. Sorry, I don't want to spend more time on debating this.